# New user registration cannot be done

Tags: python, html, django

New user registration cannot be done.
I wrote in views.py

```
def regist(request):
    regist_form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'regist_form': regist_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/regist.html', context)

@require_POST
def regist_save(request):
    regist_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if regist_form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        login(request, user)
        context = {
            'user': request.user,
        }
        return redirect('detail')

    context = {
        'regist_form': regist_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/regist.html', context)
```

in forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email','password1','password1',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

in regist.html

```html
<div class="heading col-lg-6 col-md-12">         
        <h2>New account registration</h2>
    
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="regist_save/" method="POST">         
          <div class="form-group-lg">         
            <label for="id_username">username</label>
                     {{ regist_form.username }}         
          </div>                  
          <div class="form-group-lg">         
            <label for="id_email">email</label>
                      {{ regist_form.email }}
          </div>   
          <div class="form-group-lg">         
            <label for="id_password">password</label>         
             {{ regist_form.password1 }}         
          </div>                  
          <div class="form-group-lg">
            <label for="id_password">password（conformation）</label>         
             {{ regist_form.password2 }}
             <p class="help-block">{{ regist_form.password2.help_text }}</p>         
          </div>                  
          <div class="form-group-lg">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">SUBMIT</button>         
            <input name="next" type="hidden"/>         
            </div>
          </div>
          {% csrf_token %}         
        </form>         
</div>
```

No error happens and when I put SUBMIT button,it send detail.html,so it is ok.But when I see admin site,no user is registered.
I really cannot understand why this happens.I cannot understand what is wrong.I read Django tutorial,so I think this way of writing code is ok.How should I fix this?What should I write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form variable is `regist_form` but you are trying to save `form` Try to change `user = form.save()` to `user = regist_form.save()`.

Also you need to set password for new user, you can use `commit=False` for this:

```
user = regist_form.save(commit=False)
password = regist_form.cleaned_data.get('password')
user.set_password(password)
user.save()
login(request, user)
```